# C++ function pointers inside templates

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have this problem:

```
template<typename T> class Bubu
{
...
   int (*comparer)(const T t1, const T t2);
...
public:
   Bubu(int (*_comparer)(const T t1, const T t2))
   {
      comparer = _comparer;
   }
};
```

And in another file:

```
Bubu<char*> asd(strcmp);
```

Error:

```
error C2664: 'Bubu<T>::Bubu(int (__cdecl *)(const T,const T))' : 
             cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(const char *,
             const char *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const T,const T)'
```

I don't understand why. Shouldn't the compiler see a "char*" instead of "T" there?

EDIT: the Ideone.com-ready code:

```
int asdf(const char* a, const char* b)
{       return 0; }

template class Bubu
{
   int (*comparer)(const T t1, const T t2);
public:
   Bubu(int (*_comparer)(const T t1, const T t2))
   {
      comparer = _comparer;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Bubu asd(asdf);
}
```

Comment: Must be a typo: `int (*comparer)()`

Comment: Tidy this up, please! I got about five unrelated errors when I tried to compile it. Then I gave up. Give us a single block of code that we can put through ideone.com!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `T` is `char*`, `const T` is `char* const` which isn't the same thing as `const char *`. You need:

```
 Bubu<const char*> asd(strcmp);
```

Top level const is ignored for function signatures so

```
int (*)( const char* const, const char* const );
```

is the same type as

```
int (*)( const char*, const char* );
```

so you're OK on the extra top level const although it doesn't gain you anything over the simpler `int (*comparer)(T t1, T t2);`.

Comment: You're right! And I am most happy because of that. But what would happen if I'd want to change some T's inside my template? since Bubu's type has the const keyword in it?

Comment: @cantrem: You have number of options. You could write a wrapper function that calls `strcmp` but takes pointers to non-`const char`; you could template your class in the character type and not the pointer type and used `int (*)( const T*, const T* )`; you could use some traits-style meta functions to recover `char` from `T = char*` and manufacture `const char*` from there. It really depends on what your template is supposed to provide flexibility for and what it must assume about its parameters.

Comment: I went for the quick and very very dirty solution of wrapping strcmp... but since it's a school project, it deserves to be that way! I guess the best solution would be to use std::string, like normal people do.

Answer (score 3):

If `T` is specialized as `char*`, `const T` means `char* const` (i.e. immutable pointer to a mutable `char`), rather than `const char*` == `char const*` (i.e. mutable pointer to an immutable `char`).

```
Bubu<const char*> asd(strcmp)
```

will compile.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I need that chars mutable. Any idea how to keep my Bubu<char*> declaration as it is?

Comment: To wrap strcmp into a function with non-const char* parameters is so ugly!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but your `*` in your function pointer declaration is in the wrong place (at least compared to what I've ever seen).  Instead of:

```
int (comparer*)(const T t1, const T t2);
```

It should be:

```
int (*comparer)(const T t1, const T t2);
```

Comment: it is (at least now, sorry if it was a typo before the post edit)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Bubu {
public:
    typedef int (*Comparator)(T, T);

    Bubu(Comparator inComparator) : mComparator(inComparator) { }

    int compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return mComparator(a, b);
    }

private:
    Comparator mComparator;
};

int main() 
{
    Bubu<const char*> obj(strcmp);
    std::cout << obj.compare("one", "two") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```