# Function pointer inside template function

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello Im begginer with c++ and Im stuck with this problem. I have template class as you can see bellow and there is another template method PrintSpecificObject. In real project I have a collection of differents objects and I need for example print just object which could be cast do "K". Anyway, my problem is with "PrintThatObject" method or with that how i call it in main. 
 Thanks for help.

```
     template<typename T>
        class Foo {
        public:
            std::vector<T*> v;

            template<typename K>
            void PrintSpecificObject(void(*uFunc)(K*)) {
                for (std::vector<T*>::iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) {
                    if (dynamic_cast<K*>(i) != nullptr) {
                       PrintThatObject(i);    //<------- There i call it
                    }
                }
            }

          //<------- How this method shoud look? ------>
            void PrintThatObject(int i) {
                std::cout << i;
            }
        };

    int main() {
        Foo<int*> f;
        f.PrintSpecificObject<int>(f.PrintThatObject); // Error C3867
        f.PrintSpecificObject<int>(&Foo<int*>::PrintThatObject); // Error C2664
      //  <------- Or How should i call that method?  -------> 
  }
```

Comment: You should edit and improve your question: nothing is right in the code snipet you posted. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell us specifically what you are trying to do. Until then, I'm downvoting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function pointers inside templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349214/c-function-pointers-inside-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass any representation of PrintThatObject to PrintSpecificObject.  The problem is that PrintSpecificObject takes a function pointer.  PrintThatObject is a *member* function.  [Huge difference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types)!

You could fix PrintSpecificObject, or just add an overload and it won't be ambiguous, like so:

```
template < typename Object, typename K >
void PrintSpecificObject(Object * o, void (Object::*fun)(K*))
{
    //...whatever...
    // call function
    o->*fun(some_k);
}
```

You'd call with `f.PrintSpecificObject<int>(&Foo<?>::PrintThatObject)`

The ? is whatever type you passed to Foo to instantiate the class for f.

Comment: Im happy, that you understand my problem. Thanks for this solution but what I have to do for that I can use it without that "Object" in template? 
Take it as interface 
`code`
Template<typename K>
void PrintSpecificObject(void(*pFunc)(K*);
`code`
And i need to get it work in this way. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @BartosekTom - No, there's no way to pass a member function pointer off as a function pointer.  Please read the link I put in my answer.  So if you can't add the version I gave you, then you can't do what you're trying to do at all.

Comment: Unless that member function is static that is.  If it's a static member then it's really a regular function just put into a different scope.

Comment: That "PrintThatObject" method can be whatever where, that means outside class too if thats the problem in this situation. I just need have that PrintSpecificObject in this way.

Comment: I can make another class and call that method from there or put it outside class, bud none of these works for me.